# Size of UIwebView iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I created a UIwebview to get a webpage and I have a problem about the size. When I turn my iphone the webpage do not take all the screen. please help me that also when I turn the phone the webpage fill all the screen.
Thanks

```
  #import "ViewController.h"

  @interface ViewController ()

  @end

  @implementation ViewController

  - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.google.com";
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
     NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
      [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @end
```

Comment: Take a screenshot of what actually happens on your device.

Answer (score 1):

Set `scalesPageToFit` property to YES.

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]; 
      NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
      [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];         
      [self.webView loadRequest:request];               
    }
```